# Escape every character in bash

Tags: bash

I want to take a string like this:

```
Example string 59^!#&$(
```

And turn it into this:

```
\E\x\a\m\p\l\e\ \s\t\r\i\n\g\ \5\9\^\!\#\&\$\(
```

I've tried:

`sed -e 's/./\\&/g; 1{$s/^$/""/}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/'`

as noted here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash/20053121#20053121

But as noted by [dalelane in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash/20053121#comment76357887_20053121), this does not work under vanilla installation of bash in macOS. I have confirmed this with macOS High Sierra.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you consider Charles Duffy's first comment to that question? How are you planning to use the escaped string? In the shell, you want to use double quotes instead of inserting backslashes.

Comment: Safest way to `cd` somewhere, `cp` a file, `tee -a` to a file. I'm taking into account writing/reading/navigating  to/from  files/folders that are Unicode-happy (Arabic characters, Japanese, Latin, Inuktitut, etc.) and include bash special characters. IMHO it's safer to just escape everything.

Comment: The safest and easiest method is to use quotes. For example `s='Example string 59^!#&$('; echo "$s"` -- single quotes to prevent the "$" from expanding in the assignment, and double quotes to allow variable interpolation, but prevent any other mischief.

Comment: I also read his comments but they didn't make much sense. Keep in mind I'm somewhat of a n00b with this stuff.

Comment: What if I run into a double quote inside the string?

Comment: No problem: `s='She said "Hello"'; echo "$s"` -- the shell expands the variable, then removes the outer quotes but maintains the text as a single 'word'. The quotation marks in the text are *not* further subjected to another round of expansion.

Comment: This is spelled out quite clearly in the manual: the shell performs various expansions in a particular order. See [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: Essentially, once the variable is expanded, any quotes or any other special characters have no special meaning.

Comment: This is why the `eval` command was invented: there are times when you want to create code dynamically and you want to force the shell to perform another round of expansions. But you don't use `eval` lightly, danger that way lies.

Comment: So, I see what you are asking to do as a "rookie mistake" albeit a well-intentioned one.

Comment: No problem. The issues are spelled out in (excruciating) depth at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) -- follow some of the links in the question.

Comment: Hey @glennjackman, just thought, what about a string that has both `'` and `"`?

Comment: bash has several quoting mechanisms. You can use a here-document in case of quoting hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me with bsd sed-

```
echo "I am a jelly donut" | sed 's/./\\&/g'
\I\ \a\m\ \a\ \j\e\l\l\y\ \d\o\n\u\t
```

and with your string

```
echo 'Example string 59^!#&$(' | sed 's/./\\&/g'
\E\x\a\m\p\l\e\ \s\t\r\i\n\g\ \5\9\^\!\#\&\$\(
```