# Escape control characters in bash script

Tags: terminal, bash, script, perl

I need a solution to escape control characters from a string.

What I need is to turn this:

`%f4^rH13#b$rHN`

into this:

`%f4\^rH13\#b\$rHN`

I found a solution working with GNU `sed` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash/20053121#20053121), which won't work on vanilla macOS. I also found a solution to [escape ever character on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363398/escape-every-character-in-bash). But I haven't found a solution to only escape control characters.

Answer (score 2):

A main difference between GNU sed and BSD sed is that the BSD version expects the closing `}` of a function list on a new line.

The following works on macOS (this are three distinct lines, just press <kbd>Return</kbd> before entering the `}`):

```
echo '%f4^rH13#b$rHN' | LC_ALL=C \
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9,._+@%/-]/\\&/g; 1{$s/^$/""/
}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/'
```

Comment: Would you mind posting this solution on the SO question as well? At least that was the first link that popped up when googling 'bash escape control operators'.  I think that would improve discoverability.

Comment: @Nils I left a comment (as you did). In practice I would most likely use `printf '%q' STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `perl` to do so:

```
$ echo '%f4^rH13#b$rHN' | perl -pe 's/([^a-zA-Z0-9,._+@%\/\n-])/\\$1/g'
```

This works on vanilla macOS Ventura 13.2.1, but beware that Apple might remove scripting language runtimes like `perl` in future releases. As they stated in macOS 11 release notes:

> Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. In future versions of macOS, scripting language runtimes won't be available by default, and may require you to install an additional package.